# Python how to parsing HTML with BS4

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, lxml

```
<div class="stuff">
 <div class="this">K/D</div> 
 <div class="that">8.66</div>
```

( If not clear the two divs below the top div are its children )

I'm currently trying to parse for *8.66* and I have made many attempts to parse for it using lxml and beautifulsoup. I tried running a loop to search for that value but it seems like nothing works!
If you can help please do I am absolutely lost on how to do this. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Have you read [the docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree)? BS4 (and parsing HTML in general) is complicated enough that there's really no other way to learn it than to read the explanations of the different kinds of searches and how to write them.

Comment: Thankyou I haven't I will do that. It is quite complicated from a first look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the class value:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = """
<div class="stuff">
<div class="this">K/D</div> 
<div class="that">8.66</div> 
"""
s = soup(d, 'html.parser')
print(s.find('div', {'class':'that'}).text)
```

Output:

```
8.66
```

Comment: @ItsMe Glad to help!